# How to access request data in Shopware 6 custom endpoint?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to access data sent via POST to a custom endpoint for app script.
The request service doesn't seem to contain any.

For

```
{% do debug.dump(request) %}
```

i get

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => null
]
```

Is there a way to access data sent with the request to a custom endpoint for app script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access the request over the `hook` variable:

```
{% do debug.dump(hook.request) %}
```

Refer to the [reference of all the script hooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference#custom-api-endpoint) to see what data is available under the `hook` variable.

Comment: thanks. this worked. "hook.request" is for POST params and "hook.query" is for GET params.